# Inconsistent forecast behavior when using lagged xregs in R fabletools

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r, fabletools

*This is a question I opened as an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/317) but haven't heard from the package author, so I thought I would ask the question here. Thanks!*

I am noticing some inconsistencies when forecasting with lagged xregs. Specifically, forecasts for h <= lag period. It seems like the historical data provided to the original model is not added to the new data before generating the forecast. In the example below I use the lag = 2 example from fpp3. The first forecast `fc1` is identical to the one generated in the book. In the second forecast `fc2` I augment the `new_data` by binding the historical advert data with the new advert data generated in `insurance_future`. When I do this I get a different forecast in `fc2` vs `fc1`. It seems to me like the forecast in `fc1` does not have access to the historical (xreg) data, so the TVaderts is treated as `NA` for the first two steps in the horizon. Is this correct? And if so, shouldn't that data be included as it is in `fc2`? This might be related to.

```r
library(fpp3)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.4.0 ──
#> ✓ tibble      3.1.2      ✓ tsibble     1.0.1 
#> ✓ dplyr       1.0.6      ✓ tsibbledata 0.3.0 
#> ✓ tidyr       1.1.3      ✓ feasts      0.2.1 
#> ✓ lubridate   1.7.10     ✓ fable       0.3.1 
#> ✓ ggplot2     3.3.3
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)

fit <- insurance %>%
  # Restrict data so models use same fitting period
  # Estimate models
  model(
    lag2 = ARIMA(Quotes ~ pdq(d = 0) +
                   TVadverts + lag(TVadverts) +
                   lag(TVadverts, 2))
  )

insurance_future <- new_data(insurance, 20) %>%
  mutate(TVadverts = 8)

# Forecast as shown in https://otexts.com/fpp3/lagged-predictors.html
fc1 <- fit %>%
  forecast(insurance_future)

# Manually pre-pend historic advert data to future data to ensure presence of
# lagged regressors
fc2 <- fit %>% 
  forecast(bind_rows(select(insurance, -Quotes), insurance_future)) %>%
  filter_index(as.character(min(insurance_future$Month)) ~ .)

print(fc1)
#> # A fable: 20 x 5 [1M]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model    Month      Quotes .mean TVadverts
#>    <chr>     <mth>      <dist> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 lag2   2005 May N(13, 0.23)  13.0         8
#>  2 lag2   2005 Jun N(13, 0.59)  13.0         8
#>  3 lag2   2005 Jul N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  4 lag2   2005 Aug N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  5 lag2   2005 Sep N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  6 lag2   2005 Oct N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  7 lag2   2005 Nov N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  8 lag2   2005 Dec N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  9 lag2   2006 Jan N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 10 lag2   2006 Feb N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 11 lag2   2006 Mar N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 12 lag2   2006 Apr N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 13 lag2   2006 May N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 14 lag2   2006 Jun N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 15 lag2   2006 Jul N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 16 lag2   2006 Aug N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 17 lag2   2006 Sep N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 18 lag2   2006 Oct N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 19 lag2   2006 Nov N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 20 lag2   2006 Dec N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
print(fc2)
#> # A fable: 20 x 5 [1M]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model    Month      Quotes .mean TVadverts
#>    <chr>     <mth>      <dist> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 lag2   2005 May N(14, 0.72)  13.5         8
#>  2 lag2   2005 Jun N(13, 0.72)  13.3         8
#>  3 lag2   2005 Jul N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  4 lag2   2005 Aug N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  5 lag2   2005 Sep N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  6 lag2   2005 Oct N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  7 lag2   2005 Nov N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  8 lag2   2005 Dec N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#>  9 lag2   2006 Jan N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 10 lag2   2006 Feb N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 11 lag2   2006 Mar N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 12 lag2   2006 Apr N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 13 lag2   2006 May N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 14 lag2   2006 Jun N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 15 lag2   2006 Jul N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 16 lag2   2006 Aug N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 17 lag2   2006 Sep N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 18 lag2   2006 Oct N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 19 lag2   2006 Nov N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8
#> 20 lag2   2006 Dec N(13, 0.72)  13.2         8

waldo::compare(fc1, fc2)
#> `old$Quotes[[1]]$mu`: 13.0
#> `new$Quotes[[1]]$mu`: 13.5
#> 
#> `old$Quotes[[1]]$sigma`: 0.5
#> `new$Quotes[[1]]$sigma`: 0.8
#> 
#> `old$Quotes[[2]]$mu`: 13.0
#> `new$Quotes[[2]]$mu`: 13.3
#> 
#> `old$Quotes[[2]]$sigma`: 0.77
#> `new$Quotes[[2]]$sigma`: 0.85
#> 
#> `old$.mean[1:5]`: 13.0 13.0 13.2 13.2 13.2
#> `new$.mean[1:5]`: 13.5 13.3 13.2 13.2 13.2
```

Curiously, when I create new lagged variables manually (rather than in the formula) the model results match the "base case" from fpp3 (`fc1` in my example).

```r
insurance_manlag <- insurance %>%
  mutate(TVadverts1 = lag(TVadverts),
         TVadverts2 = lag(TVadverts, 2))

fit <- insurance_manlag %>%
  # Restrict data so models use same fitting period
  # Estimate models
  model(
    lag2 = ARIMA(Quotes ~ pdq(d = 0) +
                   TVadverts + TVadverts1 + TVadverts2)
  )

insurance_man_future <- append_row(insurance, n = 20) %>%
  replace_na(replace = list(TVadverts = 8)) %>%
  mutate(TVadverts1 = lag(TVadverts),
         TVadverts2 = lag(TVadverts, 2)) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 20)

# Forecast as shown in https://otexts.com/fpp3/lagged-predictors.html
fc3 <- fit %>%
  forecast(insurance_man_future)

waldo::compare(fc1$Quotes, fc3$Quotes)
#> ✓ No differences
waldo::compare(fc2$Quotes, fc3$Quotes)
#> `old[[1]]$mu`: 13.5
#> `new[[1]]$mu`: 13.0
#> 
#> `old[[1]]$sigma`: 0.8
#> `new[[1]]$sigma`: 0.5
#> 
#> `old[[2]]$mu`: 13.3
#> `new[[2]]$mu`: 13.0
#> 
#> `old[[2]]$sigma`: 0.85
#> `new[[2]]$sigma`: 0.77
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This reproduction leads me to believe that `fc1` is correct, rather than `fc2`. If so, what is occurring in `fc2` that causes it to have a different forecast vs that in `fc1` (and `fc3`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `{fable}`, models that produce forecasts retain all information needed to produce forecasts. When using the recommended interface to get `fc1` (as shown in the book), the model is holding onto the 2 most recent values of `TVadverts`. While they were not needed to estimate the model, they are required inputs to produce the first couple of forecasts.

When using the `forecast()` function with `new_data`, the intended behaviour is for the model to produce forecasts for each time point in `new_data`. I believe forecasting from time points not at the end of the series is not yet implemented, so I will change this to produce an error.

Generally speaking, when using the `lag()` function in a model formula there is no need to prepend the historical data. The models will store and recall the needed values for forecasting.

Comment: Update: this should now produce an error - https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/commit/efaf92567440e918263b7548f4846ccb9b405496